# Query to find count of records inserted for a file for the latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm trying to create an SQL query to get the count of records every day for the latest date.

I have 4 columns in data table:

```
File_Name, Insert_TimeStamp, MobileNumber, Message_Id (unique)
```

Suppose a file is inserted with 100 records for Insert_TimeStamp 13/12/2021, File_Name would be same for all records as per date XYZ_1312021. Like wise everyday file will be inserted.

I'm just trying to create 1 new record everyday with help of SQL by looking at this datatable. Result would be like

TotalNumberRecords, File_Name, Insert_TimeStamp(latestdate), Status(received).

But I'm getting an error

> Error saving the query field. Invalid column name 'Total_Record_Received'

SQL which I created:

```
    Select Top 1
file_name,
INSERT_TIMESTAMP,
Total_Record_Received,
'Received' as Status
from
(
Select 
file_name,
INSERT_TIMESTAMP,
Count(*) as Total_Record_Received,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by file_name ORDER BY INSERT_TIMESTAMP ASC ) as rn
from [Master-SMS MessageALL] a
Group by file_name, INSERT_TIMESTAMP) t
Where t.rn = 1
```

Sample Data :

```
File_Name     Insert_TimeStamp   Mobile_Number  MessageID
xyz_13122021   13/12/2021         7814154        mm_001
xyz_13122021   13/12/2021         7516546        mm_002
xyz_13122021   13/12/2021         1541646        mm_003
xyz_13122021   13/12/2021         5446561        mm_004
xyz_13122021   13/12/2021         5456456        mm_005
xyz_13122021   13/12/2021         8749849        mm_006
xyz_12122021   12/12/2021         7814154        mm_007
xyz_12122021   12/12/2021         8749849        mm_008
xyz_11122021   11/12/2021         8749848        mm_009
```

Result :

```
File_Name     TotalRecords     Insert_TimeStamp   Status
xyz_13122021      6               13/12/2021      Received
```

Comment: Please include some sample data and expected result (as formatted text, not as image)

Comment: @Squirrel - I've edited the question with sample data and result what I'm looking for. Could you please have a look

Comment: @squirrel - I'm editing my query it gave me only 1 record which I wanted.. but not got the latest one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is a simple `GROUP BY` query

```
SELECT File_Name,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords,
       Insert_TimeStamp,
       'Received' AS Status
FROM   [Master-SMS MessageALL]
WHERE  Insert_TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(Insert_TimeStamp) FROM [Master-SMS MessageALL])
GROUP BY File_Name, Insert_TimeStamp
```

OR you can use `TOP 1` row order by `Insert_TimeStamp` descending

```
SELECT TOP 1
       File_Name,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords,
       Insert_TimeStamp,
       'Received' AS Status
FROM   [Master-SMS MessageALL]
GROUP BY File_Name, Insert_TimeStamp
ORDER BY Insert_TimeStamp DESC
```

OR if you wish to use the `row_number()`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT File_Name,
           COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords,
           Insert_TimeStamp,
           'Received' AS Status,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Insert_TimeStamp DESC)
    FROM   [Master-SMS MessageALL]
    GROUP BY File_Name, Insert_TimeStamp
) AS D
WHERE D.RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much it got worked. All the queries are giving me expected result. Just a Quick Question. Will you first query always gives for the latest record? because initially I've used that Query only, but the TA of my project rejected saying you should subquery.

Comment: for the first query, the sub-query in `WHERE` clause is for retrieving the latest `Insert_TimeStamp`